# How to run a query for each row from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns a list of Advertisers, each Advertisers has several Brands attached to it.

So I'm running this:

```
select distinct Name from tblAdvertiser
inner join tblAvertiserBrand on AdvertiserID=ID
```

So this would return a list of Advertisers and I'm trying to write a query that would loop for each row of the list that the query above would give in an automatic manner, any ideas?

Comment: Don't think in loops but in sql queries. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what are you using the 'loop' for ? quite sure you don't need a 'loop', sql behaviour is to calculate data for all rows.

Comment: You don't need the second line to retrieve all the distinct advertisers

Comment: @amber, he is selecting distinct advertisers that have an entry in tbladvertiserbrand

Comment: I'm trying to have a list of brands for each Advertiser, so looping the query would be in order to have it run automatically and export it to excel, each list of an Advertisers for a sheet in Excel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL 'loops' by default

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE WHERE advertiser_name IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT Name
   FROM tblAdvertiser
   INNER JOIN tblAvertiserBrand ON AdvertiserID=ID)
```